# b2shape Ellipse?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I'm trying to create a elliptical object in box2D (Cocos2D). So far I've used b2CircleShape for that but I've realized that it ain't gonna cut it no more, I have to have elliptically shaped body. Is it posible? I've tried with b2PolygonShape but than my edges are linear and I need them to be curved.

Anybody had a same problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: Create it yourself? As a basis, I'd use b2CircleShape as a base class and use [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Equations) for working out the maths.

Comment: that's my last option, fist I wanted to see if there's an easier way.. But as I see it now I think I'll have to create a custom b2Shape class.. I'll wait a few days and if nothing pops up I'll create my own class and post it here as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with a polygon shape and create the "ellipse" from segments: the ellipse will be a convex polygon for sure, and you can add a reasonable number of segments. This will be just an approximation, but you can fine tune later the number of segments to give you the best ration between performance and approximation to the original shape.

Answer (score 0):

I have used approximation as well. This has some performance drawbacks, but nothing major I guess. Code (Flash ActionScript 3, but you should be able to port that easily):

```
var vertices:Vector.<b2Vec2> = new Vector.<b2Vec2>();
var a:Number = _image.width / 2 / PhysicsVals.RATIO;
var b:Number = _image.height / 2 / PhysicsVals.RATIO;
var segments:int = ellipse_approximation_vertices_count; (the more the more precise shape is, but the more time it takes to do collision detection)

var segment:Number = 2 * Math.PI / segments;

for (var i:int = 0; i < segments; i++)
{
    vertices.push(new b2Vec2(a * Math.cos(segment * i), b * Math.sin(segment * i)));
}

var shape:b2PolygonShape = new b2PolygonShape();
shape.SetAsVector(vertices, vertices.length);

var fixtureDef:b2FixtureDef = new b2FixtureDef();       
fixtureDef.shape = shape;
```